# Weird bug on a very simple addition program(c++)

Tags: c++, addition

recently (just today) i set up a simple program in c++, taking two integers from the user and adding them together. However, there seems to be a small problem...

The program is split into three functions, please take a look!

```
#include <iostream>

void readNumber(int)
{
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
}

void writeAnswer(int z)
{
    std::cout << z;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int x;
    int y;

    cout << "Enter a number(integer): ";
    readNumber(x);

    cout << "Enter another number: ";
    readNumber(y);

    cout << x << "+" << y << "=";
    writeAnswer(x + y);


    return -1522;
}
```

Now here comes the funny part, whatever value you set to be x, or y, the outcome of this little program here, always seem to be as follows:

"4286062+2686868=6972930"

I would post a screenshot, yet it seems i can't...

I am sure the problem is very obvious to you, adequate reader. Help me out here... =)

**EDIT: Thanks to the help of everyone, the program is now working like butter!**

Comment: That's not how functions work. Please spend more time studying the basics of C++, for which there are many existing resources out there.

Comment: Your function readNumber isn't doing anything useful. It stores the users input into the local variable x, then immediately destroys it when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Change readNumber(int) [by value] to readNumber(int*) [by pointer],remove 'int x' inside the function and then the call in main look like readNumber(&x)

Comment: @EvyatarEvyatarr: `int readNumber()` would be better

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit -You're right, but he needs to understand the real reason for his mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In your `readNumber` function, you're expecting that the value for `x` will be visible to your `x` variable in your `main` function. But that is not the case: `x` (in `readNumber`) is only alive until you exit `readNumber`.

Now to make your code work, you should 'push' the value of `x` from `readNumber` to `main`.
To do this you could define `readNumber` to return with int, e.g.

```
int readNumber()
{
     int i;
     std::cin >> i;
     return i;
}
```

Then in `main`, you can invoke it as `int x = readNumber();`.

Your other option is to make `readNumber` to take a [reference](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html), which would make your current code work, as you had expected:

```
void readNumber(int& i)
{
   std::cin >> i;
}
```

I think the first option is more sensible in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`readNumber`does not do anything to communicate the number it reads back to the calling context. `x` and `y` in your main function do not get modified at all, so you're simply adding uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to learn C++ a bit further, it seems like you're still missing very important parts. Let me give you some explanations about your current problem for now:

```
void readNumber(int)
{
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
}
```

You should notice that you got an unnamed parameter `(int)`, since it got no name you can't refer to it from inside your function. `int x;` is then a local variable inside the functions that's completely different and got nothing to do with any variables outside it.

You're already doing the parameter correct in your other function (i.e. `void writeAnswer(int z)`) so lets change readNumber.

```
void readNumber(int x)
{
    std::cin >> x;
}
```

Now `x` is the value you pass to the function. It would work if we wanted to write it to the output like in our other function but not for reading from input. Why? By default C++ passes a copy so you don't accidentally change a value from outside that you don't want to change, so all you do is change that copy that gets destroyed when the function leaves. If you want to change the outside variable you got to pass it by reference, we do that by changing `int x` to `int& x` (x is a reference to an int).

```
void readNumber(int& x)
{
    std::cin >> x;
}
```

This should work now. References are an important part of C++ and if you haven't learned about them yet you should read further into your book or w/e you use to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to choose from

1. Via return value of the function

   int readNumber()
   {
     int i;
     std::cin >> i;
     return i;
   }
2. By reference

   int readNumber(int &x)
   {
     std::cin>>x;
   }

You should prefer the 1st type for primitive types(as is the case in this situation with int). Passing parameters with reference imposes certain overheads.
Therefore the second technique, passing by reference should be used with non primitive types( objects of classes and structs).